# Drag-and-drop implementations in JavaScript - what is easiest component to use with a tree implemented via nested DIVs?

Tags: javascript, treeview, drag-and-drop

We have a collapsible tree implementation in our web app. I need to add support for simple drag-and-drop to it.

The question is, what should I use? I know YUI has a drag-and-drop component, but people I worked with have stated it's a pain to use with multiple DIVs which overlap and comntain each other (like my tree does).

Are there any suggestions on what to use that's easier/better than YUI's D-a-D? Or if you suggest I stick with YUI as the best available, are there any tutorials/examples of how to graft it on a tree implemented via nested DIVs (the complexity is figuring out which of the DIV's in the nest the drag and drop events apply to).

Please note that I need to graft D-a-D onto an existing implementation. While it's fairly flexible, srapping it in favor of some pre-built tree that has D-a-D is not an option due to the implementation's specialized nature.

P.S. I have not tried the YUI one myself, for the fear of spending a week wrestling with it only to be told there's something much better and simpler I should have used instead. But if the consensus is that YUI is my best shot and nobody comes up with a good tutorial, I will (pending successfully doing this project) post my approach for common consumption.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Try JQuery UI

Comment: How is JQuery's D-a-D implementation compared to YUI? Especially as it relates to grafting on top of nested DIV tree?

Comment: I cant compare YUI since I havent used it.  I was simply giving a suggestion for research.  In my work with JQuery UI I have found that drag and drop is extremely easy to implement for basic to moderately complex cases but clearly for more difficult cases the effort level goes up.  However with JQuery UI there are many plugins with a little research maybe there is a plugin that will fit your needs.  Not saying this is the way to go...Im just providing an option